# Windows Phone 8(WP8) C# unsafe code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unsafe, c++-cx

**EDIT: You can use unsafe code... you just have to manually edit the proj file.**

Why or why does C# on WP8 not support unsafe code when I can use native C++ code on the phone(I did not expect this)?  I mean rly come on, I am so disappointed with what Microsoft is trying to force C# into.

Is there any MS plans to support this in the future on WP8?  I pass shader constants from C# to C++ and use unsafe code to optimize this process but on WP8 i'm going to be forced into doing this in some slow fashion on a WAY slower device compared to a PCs and it makes this very frustrating.

As an example to pass a vector4 to C++ I would do:

```
public unsafe void Set(Vector4 value)
{
    com.Set((int)&value, sizeof(Vector4));
}
```

Then in C++:

```
void ShaderVariableCom::Set(__int32 data, int size)
{
    void* ptr = (void*)data;
    if (vertexOffset != -1) memcpy(vertexBytes + vertexOffset, ptr, size);
    if (pixelOffset != -1) memcpy(pixelBytes + pixelOffset, ptr, size);
}
```

Anyone have a good fast way of doing this without unsafe code?

Comment: There is a good question in here buried amongst the frustration.

Comment: I can't find any documentation that suggests Windows Phone 8 doesn't support `unsafe`. Not to say that it doesn't, but I can't find documentation for it.

Comment: `unsafe` is a keyword in the C# specs, despite your frustration, was it removed from command line compiler?

Comment: Ya I know, I rly thought they where going to fix this in WP8.  I have it up and running and the unsafe code option is grayed out.  Trying to come up with some way to pass big sets of data to c++ from c# without it running slow.

Comment: t0mm13b: unsafe may be in the specs but just like WP7, its grayed out in the project properties

Comment: Have you seen [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27943473)

Comment: t0mm13b: Quote "Unsafe code also complicates" - This is so untrue.  But yes I did see this thread.  I have a game engine that runs on many .NET only platforms and so most of my code must be done in C#.

Comment: Wish I could help... sorry if its not any help...

Comment: @zezba9000: The main reason is around security and the app sandbox. By allowing unsafe code, they open themselves up to potentially a lot more memory exploits and other things like that.

Comment: @AlastairPitts But you can use C++ on WP8, no?

Comment: Alastair Pitts: This is not true because you can use native c++ code on WP8.  Event use it from C#.  So how does this break the sandbox?  Most sandboxing should not be done by limiting a language.

Comment: @zezba9000: my guess is that it's a legacy of WP7, which didn't obviously allow C++ and enforced the tightly rigid sandbox. As you say, it doesn't seem to make sense considering C++ is allowed. In that case, can you not just write your unsafe sections in C++ and wrap around them?

Comment: Alastair Pitts: Problem is the data is coming from C# and needs to be passed to C++ in an optimized fashion.  This is for a game engine thats mostly written in C# as its targeted for some .NET only platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

For simple vector types just do:

```
Marshal.StructureToPtr(vector, nativePtr, false);
```

And for arrays do:

```
var data = new Vector[10];
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(data[0]);
for (int i = 0; i != data.Length; ++i)
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(data[i], nativePtr + (size * i), false);
}
```

If anyone has a better answer that would be good to know too.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what C++/CX  is there to address (while maintaining the integrity of the sandbox).

For instance for passing int array from C# to C++ use `Platform::Array<int>` in your C++/CX ref class or interface definition. Check out MSDN for the specifics of how to use this type.

( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700131.aspx )

Comment: This does not handle the issue of a Vector struct type thats defined in C# and passing an array of them to C++/CX.  Correct me if i'm wrong but unsafe c# code does not break the sandbox anymore then unsafe c++ code.

Comment: Also my end goal was just to copy managed memory to a native buffer and I got that working by getting a IntPtr to native memory and just using Marshal in C#.