# How to allow unsafe code in VS2012

Tags: c#, build, windows-phone-8

All the tutorials I have read just say to go to the project's BUILD options, and check the "Allow unsafe code" checkbox. When I do this, the checkbox is disabled and can't be clicked...

This is a Windows Phone 8 Class Library, if that makes any difference.

Any ideas how to allow unsafe code?

Comment: Have you reviewed this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432361/windows-phone-8wp8-c-sharp-unsafe-code?

Comment: _Windows Phone 8 Class Library, if that makes any difference_ - Yes it does. No unsafe code allowed in the App Store.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Is there a way for me to compile a library for WP8 which uses unsafe code? Besides changing the unsafe code

Comment: You can write a Windows Runtime component in native C++ and use it in C#.

Comment: @HansPassant just answered that for me.

Comment: Yuck. I was hoping you wouldn't say that :) ..although I guess it is already written in c++ http://openil.sourceforge.net/ ...and I just need to figure out how to make it a runtime component

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. If Microsoft would let every app to crash the phone, they would take very bad feedbacks from their customers even if it's not their fault. Therefore I don’t think normal WP will ever be allowed to use unsafe code at runtime.

Comment: The article that sdcoder posted sort of addresses this. Why are they making c# "less good" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432361/windows-phone-8wp8-c-sharp-unsafe-code